# Trouble creating signed URL in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a signed URL to download a file in Google Cloud Storage, from an App Engine app written in Go. There's a nifty signing method in App Engine which I'm using, which [in theory] allows me to avoid putting a private key in my app. However, the URLs don't appear to work: I always get a 403 "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
func createDownloadURL(c context.Context, resource string, validUntil time.Time, bucket string) (string, error) {
  serviceAccount, err := appengine.ServiceAccount(c)
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }

  // Build up the string to sign.
  validUntilString := strconv.FormatInt(validUntil.Unix(), 10)
  toSign := []string{
    "GET",            // http verb (required)
    "",               // content MD5 hash (optional)
    "",               // content type (optional)
    validUntilString, // expiration (required)
    resource,         // resource (required)
  }

  // Sign it.
  _, signedBytes, err := appengine.SignBytes(c, []byte(strings.Join(toSign, "\n")))
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }
  signedString := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(signedBytes)

  // Build and return the URL.
  arguments := url.Values{
    "GoogleAccessId": {serviceAccount},
    "Expires":        {validUntilString},
    "Signature":      {signedString},
  }
  return fmt.Sprintf("https://storage.googleapis.com/%s/%s?%s", bucket, resource, arguments.Encode()), nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. There were 2 problems with my code.

I forgot to include the bucket name when building up toSign. Fix:

```
fmt.Sprintf("/%s/%s", bucket, resource),         // resource (required)
```

This returned an AccessDenied error -- progress!

The second mistake was using the XML API storage.googleapis.com instead of the authenticated browser endpoint storage.cloud.google.com. Fix:

```
return fmt.Sprintf("https://storage.cloud.google.com/%s/%s?%s", bucket, resource, arguments.Encode()), nil
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

StringToSign may require uninterpreted newlines. Could you give this a try:

```
_, signedBytes, err := appengine.SignBytes(c, []byte(strings.Join(toSign, "\\n"))) // escaped newline
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function that signs URLs is tricky, since due to the nature of encryption it's very difficult to tell what's wrong when things don't work. You may find it easier to use a library like [gcloud-golang](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud), which has a [SignedURL](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/storage#SignedURL) method.

Comment: Thanks -- a good recommendation. That library requires that I provide a private key, whereas appengine.SignBytes manages the key for me. If I were doing this anywhere but appengine I would use that method.

Comment: That's a good point. I've filed a feature request: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/issues/286

Comment: Update: This is now a feature :)